# Ficus Elastica having weird surface on leaf

Tags: plant-care

[image: leaf looking weird of my rubber plant]

My plant is healthy and no yellowing leaf. Keep growing new leaf but the younger leaf below the new growth is looking weird. Surface is unusual from the rest. Only one leaf looking strange and the rest are shiny and good.